# ssh session error by aspera connect data transfer tool

Tags: ssh, download, data-transfer, ssh-keys

I have installed aspera connect plug-in for download large data on fedora 14 linux platform.

I have configured proxy setting of our organization. Whenever i try to download some file, it throws an error :

Error -failed to open ssh session. (Code 16)

Comment: Where are you trying to download your files from ? Is that clear for you that you can only download files from servers that are running their software  ?

Comment: Thanks philant. Actually problem is from my side...I tried to download aspera demo files from their website. Also, I am trying to download big files from NCBI (National Center for Biotechnology Information) which do support aspera software.

Answer (score 1):

For Successfull transfer you need to open the following ports on you firewall:
TCP port 22 (ssh) : allows the connection with Aspera server.
UDP port 33001 : allows file transfer.
UDP ports from 33001 to 33010 for example if you want to send 10 files simultaneously.
(http://support.sportstec.com/hc/en-us/articles/202344978-Firewall-configuration-for-ASPERA)
FOr more information about how to open the ports,please refer to this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html